# Font license search

Tags: fonts, licenses

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask, but over the years, I've collected many, many fonts, but some of them I am no longer sure if I have the right license to have it installed on my system, and I have no idea how to effectively do this (for all). For example, I have a few fonts from the old Sun Office days, from old Windows 95 installs, as well as a few I might've downloaded off the web years ago (before I knew about font licensing). So how do I check whether I have the proper license/permission to use the fonts I am using on my system?

This is a Fedora Core 16 machine, if that is relevant.

Comment: Is `strings yourfont.ttf | grep opyr` coming up with useful things? (Not all font file formats will have metadata fields for copyright, though.)

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz, nope, nothing.

Comment: Better ask this on graphic design community I think.